# How does this circuit startup?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Elenco AM/FM Radio Kit - Audio Amp]

This circuit is from an Elenco AM/FM Radio kit.

How does this circuit start working when the 9 VDC power, at the top right of the schematic, is applied?

Specifically, what puzzles me is the "chicken or egg" conundrum of the first current flows. It appears to me that Q13 has to be on in order for current to flow out of its collector so the base of Q10 is energized in order for Q10 to turned-on.  With Q10 on current will flow from the 9 VDC source through D5, R49, Q10, and R48 to ground and thus turn-on Q11, which would in turn turn-on Q13.  But, I have assumed that Q13 is already on in order for Q10 to be turned on.

Do very small leakage current play a role here is getting things going?

Comment: Why is there an SD card holder in the middle of the diagram? What is it?

Comment: Vcc --->R46-->base-emitter Q11--->R50--->R47--->Q10 base-emitter---->R48--->GND

Comment: This circuit is on a small PCB which is meant to plug into the DIP socket which can also accommodate a LM386 audio amplifier IC.  This PCB circuit plugs into that DIP with headers in lieu of the LM386 to show how the circuit amplifies the audio input which will be capacitively connected to the base of Q10.

Comment: G36 - Since once Q10 is on, it turns on Q12 and in turn Q14, how does current flow out of Q11 through R50 ultimately to ground which is necessary to turn on Q10?

Comment: That's one of the functions of R47.

Comment: How does R47 get current if Q10 is off because R47 has no current?  Doesn't Q10 have to be on for Q11 and Q13 to be on, Q13 then supplying R47 with current?

Comment: I showed you the path of current at turn-on.  R46 provides the current for Q11 base-emitter (Q13 will turn-on as well), next the current will flow via R50 and R47 into Q10 base. And the current will continue to flow via Q10 base-emitter junction and via R48 to ground. As soon as Q10 base current is starting to flow the Q12 and Q14 will turn-on also.

Comment: G36 - Thanks. I see now that there are 2 pn junctions between +9 and ground with nothing but resistors in the series path.  Once I got hung up on believing Q13 and Q14 had to be on, I missed what you described.  Thanks again.